# How to make a #define use 64 bits

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following:

```
#define MAX (16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
#define MIN (1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

This will give MAX = 0. I assume that this is because the define is only using 32 bits for the define. Is there a way to use 64 bits for this or do I need to rework my code so that the define can handle a smaller value?

Comment: Use `16L` instead of `16`?

Comment: We can't tell you how to reformat your code unless you share your code with us.

Comment: `#define` doesn't interpret the numbers, it simply replaces any occurrences of `MAX` in your code with `(16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)`. We need to know how you are using `MAX` in the rest of the code.

Comment: If you want a specific type in the macro: `#define MAX ((uint64_t)16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)` or if `long long` is 64-bits on your system, `#define MAX (16uLL << 30)` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This will give MAX = 0

No, this will replace MAX with the literal tokens `( 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )` during the preprocessing phase.

> I assume that this is because the define is only using 32 bits for the define

The define isn't using *any* bits, it's just a text substitution.

> Is there a way to use 64 bits for this

Using the type explicitly is perhaps nicer than using the integer literal suffix, because it's more explicit about exactly how many bits you get:

```
#define MAX ((uint64_t)16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

or

```
#define MAX (16ll * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Comment: @Eric The `ll` suffix guarantees at least 64-bit width, or rather 63 bits of magnitude. The `ull` suffix guarantees at least 64 bits of unsigned magnitude.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is that all of those constants are implicitly of type `int`. In your case, that appears to be a 32-bit type. You need to make sure you're working with a 64-bit type if that's the behaviour you want to have.

You can typecast it to make sure it's a 64-bit type:

```
#define MAX ((int64_t)16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Or just expand the math yourself:

```
#define MAX 17179869184
```

Answer (score 3):

The macro itself is not sensitive to bitness but the code that uses it may be. If you want to ensure that the constant `MAX` is always considered a `long long`, you could define it to be "17179869184‬LL" or "17179869184i64" (MSVC-only) instead.

Better yet:

`const long long int MAX = 17179869184‬LL;`

Comment: MSVC uses `LL` also...at least recent versions.

Comment: it is something completeley different

Comment: @MarkTolonen Right; the `LL` is standard and `i64` is an MS extension

Answer (score 0):

I would rather

```
#define MAX (16LL * 1024LL * 1024LL * 1024LL)
```